# Button not reacting on mobile the same as on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, mobile

My problem may look simple but I am really stuck with it. Here is a link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VqyMpj

The button works amazing as it is, but when you open it on mobile and click on it - it doesn't work as on desktop, it doesn't get back to it's original form (just stays with x at the end).

I need it to work on mobile the same as on desktop.

Maybe the problem is with setTimeout?

Here is my JS code:

```
(function () {
    var removeSuccess;

    removeSuccess = function () {
        return $('.btn-cart').removeClass('success');
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        return $('.btn-cart').on("click", function () {
            $(this).addClass('success');
            return setTimeout(removeSuccess, 1000);
        });
    });

}).call(this);
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with the code in your question. It's entirely down to your CSS and HTML. Always provide a [mcve] **in the question itself**.

Comment: Also your `return`s do not make any sense

Answer (score 0):

Mobile devices apply the `:hover` pseudo-class when you touch an element, and don't remove it until you touch a different element.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case. But what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code - you have weird returns in yours

```js
$(function() { // on page load
  $('.btn-cart').on("touchstart click", function() {
    $(this).addClass('success');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.btn-cart').removeClass('success');
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few tries, this is what worked for me:

```
function watchForHover() {
    var hasHoverClass = false;
    var container = document.body;
    var lastTouchTime = 0;

    function enableHover() {
        // filter emulated events coming from touch events
        if (new Date() - lastTouchTime < 500) return;
        if (hasHoverClass) return;

        container.className += ' hasHover';
        hasHoverClass = true;
    }

    function disableHover() {
        if (!hasHoverClass) return;

        container.className = container.className.replace(' hasHover', '');
        hasHoverClass = false;
    }

    function updateLastTouchTime() {
        lastTouchTime = new Date();
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchstart', updateLastTouchTime, true);
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', disableHover, true);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', enableHover, true);

    enableHover();
}
```

From here: https://jsfiddle.net/dkz17jc5/19/